# why css is not working in my react component?

Tags: css, reactjs, classname

I am importing css from main.css file to Main.js file, but css is not working completely?

//This is Main.js code--
[This is Main.js screenschot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtyXD.jpg)

[This is main.css screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAzOx.jpg)

[This is website screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLGEK.jpg)

[This the folder structure ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsWVe.jpg)

I am trying to make two section of different width. But the css code does not working on inner container.

Comment: You probably have the import wrong. If you inspect in the browser and look at the console you can probably see the error. We'd have to see your folder structure to give you exact answer.  The way you have it now, it will only work if `main.css` is in your `main` folder

Comment: Do not post the photo of the code, use Markdown instead. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @JimithyPicker,  I have added the folder structure photo, can u now tell the error?

Answer (score 0):

If you have defined the same class name in a different component within the same application, then there's a conflict between the two styles. It's a common issue when you use global CSS (directly import CSS files to javascript files) in a react application.

To temporarily fix that issue you may change the class names of the divs. But it's recommended to use CSS modules to avoid such problems. CSS modules provide a namespace for the styles defined in it.

You can find more on CSS modules [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/)